# How is Trading View requesting data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, google-chrome-devtools, tradingview-api

I open dev tools on Chrome when on tradingview.com/chart and click the network tab. I'm trying to see where, if I input a new ticker in the upper left corner, TradingView is fetching the data that becomes the price chart.

When recording network activity, I've looked through all of the requests/responses, but don't see any response come in with the pricing data you would need in order to create that chart. Am I missing something? Is the data hidden somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using Websockets to pass live data.  You can view this in DevTools under the Network tab. Use the `WS` filter to show only Websocket traffic.

[image]